# Test success differences in different browsers

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

When attempting to click elements using a CSS selector, e.g

```
browser.find_element(:css, '.login').click
```

I am seeing different behaviours in different browsers. This is the behaviour I am seeing:

- Chrome (35.0.1916.114) - works as expected
- Firefox (24.0) - seems to ignore the command and move onto the next line of the test. Either that or it thinks it has clicked the element when it has not.
- Safari (7.0.3 (9537.75.14) - complains that the element is not present. Interestingly, this one doesn't even seem to wait until the page has even loaded.

I have tried using a variety of web driver versions (2.42.0, 2.39.0, 2.33.0) and different browser versions with no success.

Comment: Can you please post some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my specific problem was that Firefox doesn't like targeting link elements inside lists, whilst chrome will do it fine. For example:

The following will not work in Firefox:

```
Browser.find_element(:css, '.list-item')
```

Whereas this will:

```
Browser.find_element(:css, '.list-item > a')
```

This may have been a unique problem for the site I was testing, but it is worth bearing in mind.